# I have 1 litre of water at 45 °C. How long would it take to evaporate when ambient temperature is 25 °C?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water

As a fun experiment, I'm trying to evaporate water in my kitchen. I've heated the mixture to 45 °C, and I'm wondering how long it might take to completely evaporate.

Assume that the water is 2 cm deep in a flat pan (if that is relevant).

Comment: My guess is that we are speaking about days. Just pour the solution into something shallow and leave for several days in place with strong ventilation, I used this scheme for evaporation of solutions of some salts.

Comment: Might also depend on ambient humidity. If the relative humidity in the air is 100%, then the air is already saturated with water vapor and the water will never evaporate.

Comment: Why, if the relative humidity in the air is 100%, but the air is at 25 °C, and your water is heated to 45 °C, then it will evaporate. Though of course that would not be as fast as it could be in a less humid air, and you'll get moisture all over the place, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The evaporation rate $E_r$ can be approximated by: 
$$E_r = C \times A \times (x_s - x) = 0.013$$ kg/h

$C$... evaporation coefficient $ = 25 + 19 \times v$

$A$... water surface $= 0.03 $ m$^2$

$x_s$... saturation humidity $= 0.027$ kg/kg (at 30 °C)

$x$... absolute humidity $= 0.011 $ kg/kg (at 30 °C and 40 % rel. humidity)

$v$... air speed above water surface $= 0.08$ m/s

If you mesure the air temperature above the water surface - which I approximated with 30 °C - you can get a way better approximation for your case. Also having the rel. humidity you can then find the values for $x_s$ and $x$ in a Mollier diagram (h,x-diagram).

PS: You will waste a lot of energy when you want to obtain the water temperature at 45 °C. Heating the air instead should be more effective.

Reference: [Link (in German)](http://www.aq-technik.de/Aquarium-Rechner/aquarium-wasserverdunstung-berechnen.php)

Comment: I'm curious if you'd care to respond to a similar question I posted in SE Earth Science, here: http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/5071/evaporation-loss-formulas. I never did get a response and don't want to cross-post.

Comment: @http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/5071/evaporation-loss-formulas: Since your 1. Formula also takes the surface temperature into account, when calculating the evaporation coefficient, i´d say its more accurate. But if you were trying to calculate evaporation rates at room conditions, like in this post, then both of them should be inprecise. The only way to really be sure is to find out more about the specific test conditions, under which both formulas had been constructed.

Comment: Formula 2 does use the pond surface temperature indirectly from the saturation pressure calculated in B7.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @AstronAUT. So according to your formula (and given those approximations), it evaporates at a rate of 13grams per hour and will take a little over 3 days.
Also, just to clarify... are you saying that the water will evaporate faster in an oven than on a stove (over direct flame)?

Comment: At the same temperatures, turned on convection and if you allow the oven to constantly receive fresh air, yes of course.

Answer (score 1):

I copied some data when I was trying to predict the drying time of a paint:

"The evaporation of water does not depend on the depth of a lake.
It depends on the temperature and the wind.

At 10°C, the level of the water decreases by 0.9mm/day if the wind is zero, by 1.2mm/day with a 2m/s wind, and by 1.7mm/day with a 9 m/s wind.

At 20° C, those values are respectively 3.2 mm/day, 4.5 mm/day and 6.1mm/day, when the wind blows at 0 m/s, 2 m/s and 9 m/s.

At 30° C, the same values are respectively 6.8 mm/day, 9.6 mm/day, 12.9mm/day, when the wind blows at 0, 2m/s and 9m/s."

2 meters/second = 4.5 miles/hour; 9 m/s = 20.25 mph.

These values are taken from a book by M. Dorsey, Properties of the Water Substance, Reinhold Co., New York 1940.

And there is a detailed online calculator at https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/evaporation-water-surface-d_690.html  which starts out: "Evaporation of water from a water surface - like a swimming pool or an open tank - depends on water temperature, air temperature, air humidity and air velocity above the water surface."

It seems that air velocity across the surface is as controlling as temperature. There are always some water molecules just above the surface of the water - air blowing across the surface removes them. No air speed, no evaporation. Well, that's not a perfect approximation, but if you had a very tall container, the last centimeter of water would have to evaporate and then diffuse up to the top and then mix with air to get away, and that could take a very long time.